# Appending Pandas DataFrame when 2 Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

An empty pandas DataFrame is created:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['age','timestamp','score']).set_index(['age', 'timestamp'])
```

and more DataFrames will be appended to the initial `results` DataFrame.

```
    result = pd.DataFrame({'age': age,
                          'timestamp': timestamp,
                          'score': score
                            }).set_index(['age', 'timestamp'])

    # error then occurs at this point

    results.append(result)
```

and we get the error

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Whats the proper way to append the second DataFrame?

Comment: Your issue is that you are passing a dict, when you pass a dict for the data the values need to be iterable, so a np array or list or Series

Comment: If you don't need `results` as a `DataFrame` until all the appending is complete, then it will be faster to collect all the data in a list of tuples, and then build the DataFrame all at once:  `result = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=[...]).set_index([...])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Since your newly added record only have one row. Initializing it via a new dataframe introduces overheads. Just pass the dict to the current df via `.loc` would work in your case.

Note that adding records one by one is not performance-efficient. But if this is part of your code logic which is unavoidable, then `.loc` will give you performance far better than `pd.append()` or `pd.concat()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# create an empty df
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['age', 'timestamp', 'score'])
Out[71]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [age, timestamp, score]
Index: []

# write new record in dict, make sure the keys match df column names
new_record = {'age': 23, 'timestamp': dt.datetime(2015,1,1), 'score':98}
# use .loc to enlarge the current df
results.loc[len(results)] = new_record

Out[73]: 
   age  timestamp  score
0   23 2015-01-01     98
```